# how to get Roles associated with a user from asp.net FormsAuthentication object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, roles

How to get Roles associated with a user from asp.net FormsAuthentication object? Other than IsInRole I don't see any methods useful 
in this respect. I am looking for something like GetRoles(). All I usee is User.IsInRole("rolename") and I need to loop through
my roles to find my role of iterest. 
    is there a way to get roles from Formsauthticket itself?

Comment: Have you looked at `Roles.GetRolesForUser()`?

Comment: Please check this SO Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068445/get-current-users-role

Comment: You can also check this one, for saving the roles in the Ticket: http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/04/01/securing-an-asp-net-mvc-2-application.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Actually the code to get the Role of the user can be this one:

```
Roles.GetRolesForUser(WebSecurity.CurrentUserName);
```

I am providing you with the `WebSecurity.CurrentUserName` to get the username for the current user.

You can try to use something else like:

```
Roles.GetRolesForUser("afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan")
```

Where **afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan** is the username of the user of whom you want to get the Role.

Also note that this provides you with a `String[]` array so using a `foreach ()` loop might be the solution to filter out the result.

For More: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h930x07.aspx