# mvc - select a user in a list of users

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-identity

I've got a list of users and their role, and it lists all users in my SQL database. I wanna be able to select one of the users and change their role like in the pictures below. But I need help to get the "data" of the selected user.
I'm using MVC Identity if that matters.

[image]
Controller code who shows the list

```
var role2 = (from r in context.Roles where r.Name.Contains("Administrator") select r).FirstOrDefault();
var admins = context.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Select(y =>   y.RoleId).Contains(role2.Id)).ToList();

var adminVM = admins.Select(user => new UserViewModel
{
Username = user.UserName,
RoleName = "Administrator"
}).ToList();
```

[image]

View code:

```
@foreach (var usera in Model.Administrators)
    {
       <td>@usera.Username</td>
       <td>@usera.RoleName</td>
       <td>(bootstrap modal button)</td>
       
       bootstrap modal body:
       Current Role: <strong>@usera.RoleName</strong>
```

Then I want to remove the "selected" user from their role and add to another.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068445/get-current-users-role

Comment: I mean how do you know what user you selected in the list?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1078491/Creating-Forms-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation of the question is wrong. You have mentioned "But I need help to get the "data" of the selected user". Later you again mentioned "Then I want to remove the "selected" user from their role and add to another". The thing is that you need to bind a onClick method and pass there USER ID. See my below code,

```
<td><button onClick="openModal(USERId)" class="btn btn-default"></button></td>
```

See here "openModal" is a user-defined method where I'm passing that user Id. So now when you click this, take that value and assign it in a hidden field and as you said it will open the edit modal. See my below code,

//This is my hidden field in HTML

```
<button Type="hidden" id="myHiddenField"/>
```

//Below is the script

```
function openModal(id)
{
 $('#myHiddenField').val(id);
 //And here you can open the modal
 }
```

So now when you assign a new Role to the particular User and click on SAVE/UPDATE button, call another jQuery/ajax method like below,

```
$('#myUpdateBtn').click(function({
 //Here you can fetch the hidden field value, that is nothing but your      selected UserId
  var UserId = $('#myHiddenField').val();
  $.ajax(function(){
     url:"pass your url here",
     Type:"Put", //Pass your method type. Ex: Post, Put, etc
     Data:{Id:UserId, RoleName:yourNewRoleId},
     success:function(d){}
  })
}))
```

Comment: Don't know if I understand what you're saying, everytime a user registeres on the site, a new table row is created with their username and role. I did fetch userid now, but I can't get it to fetch the specific user that I'm selecting?